# mule : how to convert list of maps to list of JSon in dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have input data as list of maps like `[{id="200" name="aaa"},{id="100",name="shbd"}]`.
I want to transform it to JSON like below

```
{
[
  {
    id="200",
    name="aaa"
  },
 {
    id="100",
    name="shbd"
  }
]
}
```

If the fields(keys in map) do no change, then it is simple and straightforward. Now how to transform if I dont know the key values. For eg, what if after sometime the input of map is `[{"age":90},{"age","45"}]`

Comment: Did you validate the json you want to transform with a json validator? You can check if your expected json is valid json or not here https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to do specific mapping but you can go with the following , it will transform it into **JSON**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload
```

Answer (score 0):

As Anirban said, please validate the json you want to transform. 
You can use below transformation for o/p specified below:

```
Transformation
---------------
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map {
    "id" : $.id,
    "name" : $.name
}


---------------
expected output
--------------
[
  {
    id="200",
    name="aaa"
  },
 {
    id="100",
    name="shbd"
  }
]
```